# how to create slot to wrap content

Tags: vue.js

I'm looking for a way to create a slot that allows me to wrap its content with arbitrary markup, instead of replacing the content...

Consider a Template like this (obviously doesn't work):

```
<!-- this slot ... -->
<slot name="wrapper">
  <SomeComplexComponent ... />
</slot>
<!-- becomes -->
<div class="wrapper" style="background: red;">
  <SomeComplexComponent ... />
</div>
```

This is for example needed for Table components, wrapping the table header in a sticky component, to allow scrolling while keeping the header visible (see the DetailsList Fabric example: https://codepen.io/johannes-z/pen/QWbZvqx?editable=true).

In React, and Fabric, they circumvent this problem by using render functions, and passing the original render function to the *slotable* render function. This way they can wrap the original render function with arbitrary markup/components.

Is there a way to achieve this with Vue? Preferably using template syntax and not render functions / tsx.

Comment: I think that's the whole point of slots in VueJS: is to interweave content into the component. This is another fancy way of saying, I want to allow wrapping of my slotted content. In the consuming parent component, you use `v-slot` binding to assign contents to different named slots. Then, in the child component, you use `<slot>` to interweave content into arbitrary markup that you have. Read up about it here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots

Comment: Slots are replaced when consumed. The original content `SomeComplexComponent` is replaced by the consuming template. It's not wrapping, it's replacing. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Fallback-Content

Comment: That's because it's not the right way to use slots. Anything within `<slot>` elements are the "default" content, should the slot not be used. Unless you give a specific use case, it's difficult to see what you're trying to do: but I have an inkling your approach is inverted. What you want is probably `<template v-slot="wrapper"><SomeComplexContent ... /></template>`

Comment: This requires me to know what `SomeComplexContent` is, because I have to provide it when using the template... I'm trying to circumvent that, so you can consume the slot without having to know internal markup, props, etc. I wrote a quick codepen to showcase what I'm trying to achieve

EDIT: Updated pen with slots https://codepen.io/johannes-z/pen/mdJzmGw

Comment: There are no slots in your codepen.

Comment: @Terry I played around a little, this is what I came up with so far; maybe it always helps visualize the problem I have: https://codepen.io/johannes-z/pen/mdJzmGw?editors=1111. Sadly I have to use render functions for parts of the template now...